# I am getting this error message after submitting a test post: param is missing or the value is empty: content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am trying to submit a test post through my form, and I am getting this error: param is missing or the value is empty: content.  I am requiring "content" and permitting a "title".  Both fields were filled out when submitting the post or "thought" in my app.  I believe the problem has something to do with strong parameters. I can't find the answer anywhere else on the internet.  Here is my controller.

```
class ThoughtsController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end

  def new
    @thought = Thought.new(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @thought = Thought.new(params[post_params])

    @thought.save

    if @thought.save
        redirect_to @thought 
    else
        render :new
    end
  end


  private
  def post_params
    params.require(:content).permit(:title)
  end

end
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please start read about rails first. You are having too many problem in your controller. New method does not take any parameter also you are creating new object with id params. Your strong parameter also not defined in correct way. `post_params` can not be used in such way `params[post_params]` in create method.

Comment: What were the submitted parameters? (You'll find them in the log file)

Comment: just content and title I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work. You propably understand the [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) a bit wrong. If your thought object has `:content` and `:title` attributes, they should be listed in permit parenthesis - this will mean you allow their mass-assignment.

```
def create
  @thought = Thought.new(post_params)

    if @thought.save
      redirect_to @post 
    else
      render :new
    end
  end


    private
    def post_params
      params.require(:thought).permit(:content, :title)
    end
```

Comment: @post was a typo, should have been @ thought..should I require :thought instead of :post then?  My intention was to make :content required.

Comment: edited answer. Yes, take a look at link I've provided - I am sure it will be useful